# How to configure alert to apply to all instances (select *)

Tags: azure-cli

I would like to create an alert with the Azure CLI.

How should I configure the alert to apply to "Select *"?
Not by configuring all instances. But by checking the checkmark Select *, as shown in the image below:

```
az monitor metrics alert create -n $ALERT_NAME -g $RESOURCEGROUP_NAME --scopes $TARGET_RESOURCEID --condition "avg MemoryPercentage > 80" --window-size 5m --evaluation-frequency 1m --description "High CPU" --action HorizonsAlertActions --severity 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Azure monitor metrics alert, there is also a language that you need to set the value of the condition. And you can use CLI command like this:

```
az monitor metrics alert create -g ivanRG2 -n azuretestselect4 --scopes targetResourceID --condition "avg CpuPercentage > 90 where Instance includes InstanceName"  --window-size 5m --evaluation-frequency 1m --action yourAction --description "test select"
```

And the screenshot of the result will show:

[image]

Then as you wish that the "select *" means choose all the instances existing. For more details, see [`az monitor metrics alert create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/metrics/alert?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-metrics-alert-create).

Comment: Am I wrong or does this command doesn't check the checkbox that I show in my screenshot? The only difference I see is you have added " where Instance includes InstanceName" to the condition. You say something about language in your answer, but I do not understand what you mean. Btw, selecting all instances is something different then select *. This also selects future instances if for example automatic scaling is configured.

Comment: The correct part in the ARM looks like this. Now I try to translate it to CLI. Otherwise I use the ARM:
"dimensions": [
          {
            "name": "Instance",
            "operator": "Include",
            "values": [
              "*"
            ]
          }
        ],

Comment: Unfortunately, you just can select all instances with `*` through portal or template. CLI does not support to set the value with `*`, just can set the value with the exact instance name.

Comment: It's not possible to configure select *. And we really need it. The same goes for alerts on a servicebus for example for all current and in the future created topics. I've filed a bug for this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/8377
Till it's working with the CLI I'm using an ARM template which does work.